# CSS pseudo:after working perfectly in Chrome but not in Firefox or Internet Explorer

Tags: css

I am using pseudo after element for forward pointing arrow in [this](http://www.firebrand.co.ke/underconstruction/). The code works well for Google Chrome but for Firefox or Internet Explorer it is not therefore ending up distorting the layout of the web page. Especially this section **a series of fires**. The pseudo element is used below the title of the section and is the one calling the forward pointing arrow after the dashed line.

The code is here:

```css
#article::after {
  content: url('../images/iconas.png') no-repeat;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}
#article1::after {
  content: url('../images/iconas.png') no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}
.hr {
  margin-top: 50px;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  border-top: 1px dotted #281e12;
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 1px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<article class="col-md-12 text-center dark-text">
  <h1 style="text-align:left;"><span class="animated" data-fx="bounceInRight">A series of fires</span></h1>
  <article id="article">
    <hr class="hr"></hr>
  </article>

</article>
```

Comment: What versions of browsers are you running?
https://css-tricks.com/browser-support-pseudo-elements/

Answer (score 3):

There is no value `no-repeat` for `content` property. Remove it and the code will work. Chrome seems to ignore that value and display the icon.

**Error:**

[image: CSS Validator Error]

**Output in Firefox:**

[image]

Comment: when i open [this](http://www.firebrand.co.ke) on mobile phone some words overlap each other instead of having a break and go to the next line.

Comment: Hey, Billeh. Please open a new question since it is out of context of the current one.